# two way data binding in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am creating a web app with the help of angularjs,

on one of my button click i am calling a web service through angularjs

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public void getuprec(string id)
    {
        List<object> selectrecd = new List<object>();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from erp_admin.CompanySonVinUnitVenueRpt where comsonvinid in (select id from companysonvinunitvenue where id='"+id+"')",con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(dr.Read())
        {
            selectrecd.Add(new
            {
                attendee1 = dr["comattendee1"].ToString(),
                attendee2 = dr["comattendee2"].ToString(),
                totalmale = dr["attendeetotalmale"].ToString(),
                totalfemale = dr["attendeetotalfemale"].ToString(),
                unit1 = dr["unitattendee1"].ToString(),
                unitd1 = dr["unitattendee1desig"].ToString(),
                unit2 = dr["unitattendee2"].ToString(),
                unitd2 = dr["unitattendee2desig"].ToString(),
                unit3 = dr["unitattendee3"].ToString(),
                unitd3 = dr["unitattendee3desig"].ToString(),
                unit4 = dr["unitattendee4"].ToString(),
                unitd4 = dr["unitattendee4desig"].ToString(),
                unit5 = dr["unitattendee5"].ToString(),
                unitd5 = dr["unitattendee5desig"].ToString(),
                remarks = dr["remarks"].ToString()
            });
        }
        con.Close();
        var json = js.Serialize(selectrecd);
        Context.Response.Write("{" + '"' + "selectrecd" + '"' + ":" + json + "}");
    }
```

this is my webservice which is working fine (i tested) and my angularjs file

```
                 $scope.updatefunction = function (param) {
                        $http.get('/frmattendencerptqed.asmx/getuprec', {
                            params: {
                                id: $scope.updateparam.comsonvinid
                            }
                        })
                        .then()
                        {

                        }
                    }
```

this is my angularjs

this is my input field

```
<input type="text" ng-model="remarks" style="width:100%;" />
```

now i need to take the previous value from my database and bind the value on my textbox, and if user edit the textbox then the value must be updated on button click

how i need to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this is my input field

```
<input type="text" ng-model="remarks" style="width:100%;" />
```

> now i need to take the previous value from my database and bind the
>   value on my textbox, and if user edit the textbox then the value must
>   be updated on button click

Which one `remarks` property ?
In your webservice you returns a json object which contains a array of structured objects which each one may contain a `remark` property.
Can you post the resulted json of webservice call in order to give us more details ?

About how to retrieve and bind the data in your angular js controller, here is my answer.
From https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http
you can retrieve response from data property in returned object.

> data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the
>   transform functions.

So you can do something like that:

```
$scope.updatefunction = function (param) {
                        $http.get('/frmattendencerptqed.asmx/getuprec', {
                            params: {
                                id: $scope.updateparam.comsonvinid
                            }
                        })
                        .then(                  
                                   // handling if ok
                                function(response){
                                 $scope.remarks=response.data.selectrecd[indexYourWish].remarks 
                                },

                                function(errResponse){  
                                   // handling if error
                                    return $q.reject(errResponse);
                                }
                             );                                
                    }
```

As explains previously, I refer to an array to retrieve the information in response.data with an index you should define or not use at all index if you don't return a array.

`remarks` should be a variable in the scope of your controller.
The more relevant syntax to use for controller depends on how you declare things in Angular (Personally, I avoid `$scope.xxx` syntax).
Post more of your JS code if you want a more precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's just how `angularjs` normally works, the two way databinding follow this tutorial:
http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_databinding.asp
you'll see that what you only need is to call the update function from your controller and pass it the variable you bind to the input.
Of course this variable assigned to `$scope` or to `this` in the controller (there are two ways).